# OpenAL/ALUT - Loading wav files

Tags: openal

I'm using the following function:

`_alutLoadWAVMemory_((ALbyte *)myBuf,&format, &data, &size, &freq, &loop);`

I have 2 questions:

1. I've read online that the function is deprecated, does anyone know why? More important - what should I use instead?
2. Is the variable *format* assigned with data regarding the format after I call `_alutLoadWAVMemory_`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few candidates for functions to use instead, see the [Alut documentation on loading](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/The%20OpenAL%20Utility%20Toolkit.htm#Loading). I think the closest equivalent to LoadWAVMemory would be 'alutCreateBufferFromFileImage'.